# how to join two table in one table mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, phpmyadmin

I have problem in my project. 
I have two tables. First table contain this row

```
(id1,name,address)
```

second table contain

```
(id2, deperment)
```

I want to mix two table in one which contains

```
(id1,name, address,department)
```

and i have in my two table alot of data 
i want to show one row from first table with another one with second table 
not show all data
example

table 1 (1,max,londan) , (2,john,usa)
table 2(1,programming) , (2, hr)

i want to show in this shape 
(1,max,londan,programming)

just one row that show

i work on phpmyadmin

please help me

Comment: Do you want to create a new table that contains the data from both tables or just query data like that ?

Comment: no i dont want create new table

Comment: i want to show to user as one table contain both two table information

Comment: You do not seem to have a foreign key that relates the two tables. You should read about foreign keys in database design.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use "join" keyword like:

```
select id1,name,address,deperment
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id1 = t2.id2
```

You can also use "left outer join" instead of "inner join" to see all records from table 1 even though there is no match in table2 for them. Please try and see the difference.

Comment: show error #1054 - Unknown column 'tab1.id1' in 'on clause'

Comment: There is no "tab1" in the answer. Please copy and paste appropriately.

Comment: but the problem

Comment: he show all data in the two table and i want to show only data of id 1 in two table

Comment: inner join shows such records whose ids are matching with other table, whereas left outer join shows all data from the first table although there is no match. If you strictly want to show only first row, you can try to add TOP 1 in your select query: select TOP 1 id1,name,deperment

Comment: More about JOINs are here [mysql JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)